# Would Youtube crack down on upvoting your own comments from several accounts to promote your website?

Tags: youtube

What would happen if I used several accounts to upvote my own youtube comments to promote my website? Would youtube do something? What would youtube do?

The comments themselves are acceptable, I'm asking about upvoting my own comments

Comment: Are you really asking us if you will get caught if you cheat a particular way?

Comment: You can bet your life that YouTube (ie. Google) has many algorithms in place to (try to) prevent users from gaming the system.

Comment: There's really no way for us to know, and opinion-based questions are off-topic here, but the opinions expressed so far don't look positive...

Answer (score 1):

Youtube is a search engine and is owned by Google, which knows all and sees all. Your search results will drop almost certainly. you can probably game the system a bit but expect to be caught and punished (with bad ranking) eventually.